# How to get date, time and amount from String

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode, nsstring

I have

```
NSstring *str = @"Existing applications can be improved or extended on 11-01-2014 at 4 PM for 120$ ";
```

From the above string I want to get date,time and amount. The above string I am trying to get dynamically..

What I have tried is

```
NSArray *arySeperator = [result componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
for(int i=0;i< [arySeperator count];i++)
{

}
```

Unable to proceed further..

Please any help or suggestion on how to proceed further?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this approach is better for finding dates: It uses [NSDataDetector](https://developer.apple.com/librarY/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which detects semi-structured information such as dates, addresses, links, phone numbers and transit information.

```
 NSString *str = @"Existing applications can be improved or extended on 11-01-2014";

    NSError *error;
    NSDataDetector *dataDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];

    NSDate *date = [dataDetector firstMatchInString:str
                                            options:NSMatchingReportCompletion
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)].date;



    NSLog(@"date: %@", date);
```

Comment: Ur answer is working in all scenarios.. IS it possible to get time using the same.

Comment: Yes if it detect a time, see [NSTextCheckingResult](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
 NSString *str = @"Existing applications can be improved or extended on 11-01-2014";
    NSString *aStrDate = [str substringFromIndex:[str rangeOfString:@" " options:NSBackwardsSearch].location + 1];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    // this is imporant - we set our input date format to match our input string
    // if format doesn't match you'll get nil from your string, so be careful
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    // voila!
    dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:aStrDate];
```

Comment: Just change [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"]; as per format present in sting